# Failed to convert property value of type C3P0PooledDataSource to required type javax.sql.DataSource for property dataSource

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jboss, c3p0

I have been gathering many helpful answers from this site in the last few weeks.  I joined so that I could +1 to some of the answers I found most help, but couldn't do that just yet.  But Thanks!

My problem is a JBoss 7 AS deployment error that I can't seem to track down any information about.  It started out a a tutorial about Spring, Hibernation, and MySql using C3P0.

This is the log from the server showing the error that I'm trying to correct.

```
11:50:30,062 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:607) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:80) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

11:50:30,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
11:50:32,000 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) JBAS018210: Register web context: /S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
11:50:32,421 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
11:50:32,500 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11:50:39,125 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:442) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:550) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:442) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:550) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:463) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:494) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:488) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1392) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 55 more

11:50:39,765 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.19-jbossorg-1 20130304-0420 for context '/S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
11:50:55,984 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1
11:50:57,828 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start, will stop it
11:50:57,828 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11:50:57,875 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host."/S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
    ... 7 more

11:50:58,203 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 3) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
11:50:59,171 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: S4Me-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) in 940ms
```

A copy of my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                             "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory name="">
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

My applicationContent.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd"
    >

     <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
     <context:annotation-config />

     <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
      as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the 
      correct base-package -->
     <context:component-scan
      base-package="org.S2Me.MyHealth.client,org.S2Me.MyHealth.controller,org.S2Me.MyHealth.model,org.S2Me.MyHealth.server,org.S2Me.MyHealth.service" />

     <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming 
      model. Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
     <mvc:annotation-driven />

     <!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
     <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />

    </beans>
```

hibernate-content.xml the one causing the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            "
>

    <!-- <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" 
        /> -->

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<!--          <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" /> -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.S2Me.MyHealth**.*" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.jboss.C3P0PooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close"
    >
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/s2me" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="LexoR" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    >
        <property name="sessionFactory" value="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
    <listener>
  <listener-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
  </listener-class>
   </listener>

</web-app>
```

I'm using Eclipse 4.3.0, Maven 3.1, Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, JBoss EAP 6.1 in standalone configuration.

Sorry for the length of this question, but I wanted to supply the information to get the help.
Any ideas?  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: A note on your configuration, you have 2 dispatcher-servlets both loading the same configuration. Why? Why not simply have 2 mappings to the same servlet, saves you resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class [`C3P0PooledDataSource`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/jboss/C3P0PooledDataSource.html) does not implement `javax.sql.DataSource`. It is used for something completely different, JMX notifications.

Use [ComboPooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  That corrected my problem.  Thank you.